# Errors while restoring the content database from one Server Farm to another Server Farm

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, content-database, restore

I have taken the backup of my existing content db and restored it in a new SPFarm. Both farms are in sync. The same versions have been installed. SP1 & APRIL 2017 CU. (I have verified this).

Now, I have attached the restored contentdb to my new SP farm's SQL instance. and I went to Central Admin and gave details for creating a new web appln in this new farm. I gave the name of the restored content db in the textbox provided for content database name, while creating this new web appln.

Web appln got created, but when I navigated to the home page, and other custom pages, it shows many errors.

I went to event viewer, and got this error:

> Log Name:      Application
>    Source:        Microsoft-SharePoint Products-SharePoint Foundation
>    Date:          6/22/2017 3:31:01 AM
>    Event ID:      3760
>    Task Category: Database
>    Level:         Critical
>    Keywords:
>    User:          mydomain\muser1
>   Computer:      srvr0001
>   Description:
>   SQL Database 'WSS_Content_5414d7a493df4501b721142d5eff8807' on SQL Server instance 'srvr001\MSSQLSERVER_NPD' not found. Additional error information from SQL Server is included below.
>
> Cannot open database "WSS_Content_5414d7a493df4501b721142d5eff8807" requested 
>         by the login. The login failed.
>   Login failed for user 'domain1\muser1'.
>   Event Xml:
>   
>     
>       
>       3760
>       15
>       1
>       3
>       0
>       0x4000000000000000
>       
>       222978
>       
>       
>       Application
>       srvr001domaincomputer1
>       
>     
>     
>       WSS_Content_5414d7a493df4501b721142d5eff8807
>       srvr001\MSSQLSERVER_NPD
>       Cannot open database "WSS_Content_5414d7a493df4501b721142d5eff8807" requested by the login. The login failed.
>
> Login  failed for user 'domain1\muser1'.

I have verified that the user is having full privileges on both web appln, and SQL server end.

Answer (score 1):

The way that I'd approach this is:

1. Back up the content database and restore it to the new SQL Server.
2. Change the DB owner to match the farm/database access account for the new farm, within SQL Management Studio, use the following commands to achieve this:

   USE DBName

   EXEC sp_changedbowner 'Domain\FarmAccount'
3. Create a new web application, use a temporary database name (we're going to delete this DB shortly). Ensure that the web application authentication type (classic/claims) is the same as that of the source farm - this is important!
4. Attach the content database migrated from the old farm to the new farm using PowerShell. See [Mount-SPContentDatabase](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607581.aspx) for details.
5. Delete the temporary content database created with the web application. This can be done from within Central Administration.
6. If your new farm is in a different domain, you'll need to change the user information in SharePoint to the new domain. Use the Move-SPUser cmdlet to achieve this. See [Move-SPUser](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607729.aspx) for details.
7. Test access to your new content web application.

Let us know how you get on!

Answer (score 0):

Create a new web application, detach the existing content DB and attach the restored Content DB.

Comment: hi Achiever SP, i have done the same, but the errors , I have listed down , is the same, after performing your suggested steps. The (7) the step is where i am getting full of errors. Upto Step #6 , I also done the same.

Comment: The farm account should have DB Owner access on the restored Content DB.